# Не работает AJAX запрос

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]php скрипт выполняется, но $_request пустой.

```
<form id="form">
</form>
...
<textarea id="input" name="input" rows="10" form="form"></textarea>


$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".glyphicon").click(function () {
        $("#form").submit();
    });

    $("#form").submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "handler.php",
            data: $(this).serialize()
        }).done(function () {
            alert('done')
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**php**

```
$fp = fopen('asdf.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $_REQUEST["input"]);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Что содержит массив `$_POST`?

Comment: $_POST абсолютно пустой

Comment: В инструментах во вкладки `network` после отправления он должен появится, посмотрите или покажите что-то отправляется?

Comment: Возможно у вас проблемы с записью в файл, пробовали добавлять что-нибудь, кроме этих данных, просто любую строку?

Comment: @Mr_Epic, если `$_POST` действительно пустой, то запись тут не при чем.

Comment: добавил скриншот

Comment: @Mr_Epic может это из за того что сервер phpstorm?

Comment: Всё отправляется, вы выводили `var_dump($_REQUEST)`, если нет, замените весь код на эту строку, отправьте запрос и покажите вкладку `response` там же. (на счёт phpstorm, на врятли)

Comment: @Mr_Epic <br />
<b>Deprecated</b>:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
array(0) {
}

Comment: Похоже что и правда дело в `phpstorm`, php как-то не правильно настроен. У вас стоит последняя версия? Переустанавливать не пробовали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в php сервер, он неправильно настроен, это видно по ошибкам, выдаваемым при запросе:

> Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated
>   and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set
>   'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the
>   php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in
>   Unknown on line 0

Попробуйте переустановить `phpstorm` или почитайте, где находится сам php сервер в phpstorm, и настройте его, в клиентском и серверном коде всё в порядке.

Comment: вообщем, скачиваю Open Server, попробую запустить на нём...потом отпишусь получилось или нет.

Comment: все заработало, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_form.asp -

> The form attribute is new in HTML5.
>
> IE - not supported.

В Chrome и Firefox js код из Вашего вопроса работает:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".glyphicon").click(function () {
        $("#form").submit();
    });

    $("#form").submit(function () {
      var formData = $(this).serialize();
      alert(formData);
      /*$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "handler.php",
        data: $(this).serialize()
      }).done(function () {
        alert('done')
      });*/
      return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
</form>
...
<textarea id="input" name="input" rows="10" form="form">test</textarea>
<button type="button" class="glyphicon">Submit</button>
```

Comment: я использую последний хром